# Inserting Key Pairs into Lua table

Tags: lua

Just picking upon Lua and trying to figure out how to construct tables.
I have done a search and found information on table.insert but all the examples I have found seem to assume I only want numeric indices while what I want to do is add key pairs.

So, I wonder if this is valid?

```
    my_table = {}
    my_table.insert(key = "Table Key", val = "Table Value")
```

This would be done in a loop and I need to be able to access the contents later in:

```
    for k, v in pairs(my_table) do
        ...
    end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There are essentially two ways to create tables and fill them with data.

First is to create and fill the table at once using a [table constructor](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.7). This is done like follows:

```
tab = {
    keyone = "first value",      -- this will be available as tab.keyone or tab["keyone"]
    ["keytwo"] = "second value", -- this uses the full syntax
}
```

When you do not know what values you want there beforehand, you can first create the table using `{}` and then fill it using the `[]` operator:

```
tab = {}
tab["somekey"] = "some value" -- these two lines ...
tab.somekey = "some value"    -- ... are equivalent
```

Note that you can use the second (dot) syntax sugar only if the key is a string respecting the "identifier" rules - i.e. starts with a letter or underscore and contains only letters, numbers and underscore.

[P.S.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postscript): Of course you can combine the two ways: create a table with the table constructor and then fill the rest using the `[]` operator:

```
tab = { type = 'list' }
tab.key1 = 'value one'
tab['key2'] = 'value two'
```

Answer (score 7):

Appears this should be the answer:

```
my_table = {}
Key = "Table Key"
-- my_table.Key = "Table Value"
my_table[Key] = "Table Value"
```

Did the job for me.

Comment: Very nice of whoever voted me down as I tried to understand a new language. That was a step closer and I later figured out that "my_table[Key]" works.